# Why do so many U.S. politicians hold pro-Zionist policies?

Tags: united-states, israel

Why do all the main current and past U.S. presidential candidates hold pro-Zionist policies?

<sup>Theodor Herzl was the founder of Zionism. [Obama visited his grave and honored him.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcVH-_LJch4) [All the main 2016 U.S. presidential candidates gave their support to the State of Israel at AIPAC in their March 2016 conference.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23TJwROwifY)</sup>

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”](http://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: "_This question does not appear to be about governments, policies and political processes within the scope defined in the help center._" The question is about why all the main U.S. presidential candidates hold pro-Zionist policies. How could that be off-topic?

Comment: I could be wrong, but given history, I suspect the average Jewish person is more likely to vote.

Comment: @PhilLello Not every jew is automatically a zionist. Please do not mix anti-zionism with anti-semitism. The first is a legitimate political standpoint, the second religious discrimination.

Comment: @philipp Your reply doesn't follow my comment, which wasn't anti-anything.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm How is asking why U.S. politicians hold pro-Zionist policies "a rant in disguise"?

Comment: @PhilLello - that's rather irrelevant. Most US Jews vote for the party that is the least Zionist of the two (Democrats) in overwhelming majority (80 or 90%).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Israel is the most important partner of the United States in the middle-east. It's the only country in the region with a value system and culture similar to that of the United States.

The only other important geopolitical ally of the United States in the region is Saudi-Arabia, but that partnership is quite unstable due to the extreme ideological differences.

So losing the support of Israel would be very detrimental to the geopolitical interests of the United States in the region.

Also, many US companies have close ties with the Israelian economy, especially with the high-tech industry in and around Haifa and Tel Aviv. Severing these ties due to diplomatic differences would be a strong blow to the US economy.